# Table and span overlay

Tags: html, css, html-table

http://jsfiddle.net/PR8y3/

How can I make the button on top right so the background fills the `<th>` completely in this area, without these margins around it?

Comment: Your question title has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Sry, that was a misclick, fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you have a padding:3px on the th of the table. 
I changed the markup a little by adding a couple of classes and a span for the title.

```
<tr>
       <th class="title" colspan="2"><span class="main">Title </span><span class="pull-right"><a href="#">button</a></span>
       </th>
   </tr>


.table.table-thin thead th.title {padding:0px}
.table.table-thin thead th.title span {padding:3px;}
```

Here the updated forked jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/zp5hC/1/

Comment: how would you fix the title which is now too high ?

Comment: I could see that this entire row could be done in another way. But I just tried this line in CSS and it worked:
.table.table-thin thead th.title span.main{ line-height:20px;  }

Answer (score 0):

insert to your css `display:block;`